# Assigning ID to div from GeoJSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet, geojson

I have some GeoJSON data that are assigned to ids, like so:
[image]

The coordinate values from this data are used to create markers in [LeafletJS](http://leafletjs.com/). I have attempted to assign the id to each marker like so:

```
layer.markerID = feature.properties.id;
```

However, I would like to assign the same id from the GeoJSON to a div that will eventually display other aspects of the data, such as "firstname" and "lastname." This way, the div id and the marker id would be linked together, depending on which marker was clicked. So if a marker with an id of 99 was clicked, then the data in the div (which would have an id of 99) would correspond to that marker. The idea is that these ids are generated dynamically

I'm just not quite sure how to go about tackling this. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

*Edit: Just adding some additional code. Here is how I am creating the markers for my map:*

```
$.getJSON("json.php", function(json) {
    var testlayer = L.geoJson(json, {
      style: function (feature) {
        return feature.properties.style;
      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.markerID = feature.properties.id;
        layer.bindPopup("<strong>ID:</strong> " + feature.properties.id + "<br>" + "<strong>Name:</strong> " + feature.properties.firstname + " " + feature.properties.lastname);
      }
    })
```

Comment: Could you post some more of your code? E.g. the part where you create the marker etc. Would be easier to help you. Have you looked at [this example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) from the leaflet docs?

Comment: Hey @Hinrich, I just added more of my code. I think that should be enough for all of the code that's relevant to this question, but please let me know if you need me to add more! Also, I did look at that example from Leaflet; it was really helpful in informing how I should add the markers.

Comment: At first sight, this looks good to me. What happens when you click on the a marker?

Comment: When I click on one of the markers, I get a popup with **ID:** 99 and then on a separate line, I get **Name:** Eula Love. It looks like [this](http://i62.tinypic.com/2ch7u6h.png). This is true for my other markers as well. They all have their respective associated IDs and text, taken from the GeoJson.

Comment: Ok, so your question is solved?

Comment: No, I'm just not sure how to figure out how to get the id from each marker and assign them to a specific div. For instance, if I click on a marker with an id of 99, I want a div to appear that has the same id and displays the GeoJSON data that relates to that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally managed to figure it out. Here's what I came up with in case anyone else ever has this issue.

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.markerID = feature.properties.id;
        layer.bindPopup("<strong>ID:</strong> " + feature.properties.id + "<br>" + "<strong>Name:</strong> " + feature.properties.firstname + " " + feature.properties.lastname + "<br>" + "<strong>Location Details:</strong>" + " "  + feature.properties.locationDetails);
        layer.on({ click: slideData });
        function slideData(e){
          document.getElementById("box1").setAttribute("id", feature.properties.id);
          document.getElementsByClassName("fullName")[0].innerHTML = feature.properties.firstname + "&nbsp;" + feature.properties.lastname;
          document.getElementById("ageNumber").innerHTML = feature.properties.age;
        }
```

By keeping everything within the same function, I was able to access the JSON and make use of the document.getElementById and document.getElementsByClassName methods to place the text into the areas that I wanted. :)

Also, thanks @Hinrich for your help! Your suggestions really helped me think through the problem and get to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set a click listener in the `onEachFeature` function.

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.markerID = feature.properties.id;
        layer.bindPopup("<strong>ID:</strong> " + feature.properties.id + "<br>" + "<strong>Name:</strong> " + feature.properties.firstname + " " + feature.properties.lastname);
        layer.on({ click: whenClicked });
}
```

And then have a function that gets called when clicked:

```
function whenClicked(e) {
    // e = event
    console.log(e);
}
```

Look inside the event object, it should give you the feature.

Comment: I didn't realize I could add a function in there like that. Interesting. Okay, so after doing that I opened the event object in the console and got [this](http://i59.tinypic.com/w2hhxf.jpg). So the assigning of the ID (from the GeoJSON) to the div would need to occur within the whenClicked function...  What do you think would be the best way to do that?

Thank you so much for your help by the way, @Hinrich!!! :)

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of:
`document.getElementById("example").setAttribute("id", feature.properties.id);` Maybe... But when I do that, it says "feature is not defined" :(

Comment: When you inspect the event's object further, what is inside the `target` attribute? Sorry, i do have time to try it myself right now.

Comment: It's cool. Inside the `target` attribute, it says e. So `target: e`